# How to track the cart Id of any given website?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, event-tracking

**Goal**: Creating a web app that tracks eCommerce user's behaviour on a given website. I'm creating a tracking js script that enables me to track the quantity of cart and when the cart is abandoned.

**The problem:** Since I don't know the DOM structure of a given website, I cannot know which Id I need to get using document.GetElementById('#cartID')

**My POTENTIAL solution:** *I plan on using C# asp.net to create the back-end*, so perhaps I can(?) try to download each website page, render it on the app and allow the user to select where the cart is by *clicking on the cart*, then on the backed i can try to located the x and y pos of the mouse, figure which element was clicked on and identify the ID attribute that way.

My solution seems inefficient and over complicated. Is there a better way of solving this problem?

**Additionally** 
I don't want to store cart data on the back-end. The problem is simply to figure out the id that is 'cart' and if it has a value (which is the easy bit). The hard bit is figure out the id that is 'cart', the script is suppose to be used by various web developers so the structure and naming of id is different.

Comment: Welcome to So. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Your question is currently off topic: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ Or another: _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this easily using `services` or `rootScope` if you are using angular js.

If you are not using Angular Js then,to track the cart data you should use local storage in the following way.

```
var cartValue = [];
cartValue.push({itemId:123, itemName:'XYZ', itemPrice:23.12})
localStorage.setItem("myCart", cartValue);
```

when ever in the page you want to update the cart or want to fetch the cart data do the following things.

to Fetch the cart data:

```
localStorage.getItem("myCart");
```

to update the cart value from any other page or from the same page:

```
cartValue = localStorage.getItem("myCart");
cartValue.push({itemId:124, itemName:'ABC', itemPrice:63.18}
localStorage.setItem("myCart", cartValue);
```

Comment: I don't want to store cart data on the back-end. The problem is simply to figure out the id that is 'cart' and if it has a value (which is the easy bit). The hard bit is figure out the id that is 'cart', the script is suppose to be used by various web developers so the structure and naming of id is different.